# Appium - Find second element by xpath c#

Tags: c#, selenium, appium

I am trying to enter the username and password for a native application using Appium C#. The elements on the page have not been set up with unique IDs and therefor only have the class name.

```
_driver.FindElement(MobileBy.XPath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='0' and @password='false']")).SendKeys("username");
_driver.FindElement(MobileBy.XPath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='0' and @password='true']")).SendKeys("password");
```

This will enter the username in the correct field, but then will remove the username and enter the username + password in the same field

When I change the index to [1] and [2], the username is find but get NoSuchElementException error for password

Comment: ok, what is your problem?

Comment: So what is your question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: it enters the username fine. However it then enters the username and password in the same field. When I change the index to 1 and 2, it throws up a NoSuchElementException

Comment: It would be nice if you provide HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to figure out why it wasn't finding the element. Unbeknownst to me, if the keyboard is open and covering the field you are looking for then it will not be able to find the element.

Using `_driver.HideKeyboard();` after each send keys action is work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below
driver.findElementByXPath("(//android.widget.RelativeLayout)[2]").click();
if its not working use
driver.findElementsByClassName("android.widget.Button").get(1).click();
Or
You can also add text box to list and start accessing it one after another, below is the code
List a=driver.findElementsByClassName("android.widget.EditText");
        a.get(0).sendKeys("vijay12358");
        a.get(1).sendKeys("9035253309");